# Do the Native American names Pocahontas and Pocatello share a common linguistic root?

Tags: cognates

Do the Native American names Pocahontas and Pocatello share a common linguistic root, since they both start with "Poca"?

Answer (score 8):

The etymologies of those two names is at best conjecture. Given that the individuals in question (the town is named after the [chief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocatello_(Shoshone_leader))) are from completely unrelated tribes speaking unrelated languages (Pocahontas – an Algonkian tribe given her father's name, "Powhatan"; Pocatello, whose native name was Tondzaosha – member of the Shoshone tribe, whose language is part ofthe Uto-Aztecan group), there is no basis for thinking that there is anything in common between the names. It is not even established that "Pocatello" is a word of Shoshone.